# Shiny plots not showing in Rmarkdown tabs

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, plotly

I am trying to use tabs in an `Rmarkdown` document together with plots.  But I can't seem to get the plot in the second tab to display.     See the attached sample code for an example.   If I remove `{.tabset}`,  then everything would display fine.

I think if i can force a refresh within the shinyApp when switching tabs, that probably would do the trick, but I can't figure out how to do that.

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
runtime: shiny
---

# Main Page {.tabset}

## Page 1
```{r, echo=FALSE}
require(plotly)
require(dplyr)
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Page 1"),
   mainPanel(fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plot"))
   )),
server = function(input, output) {
   output$plot = renderPlotly({
      data.frame(x=seq(1,10)) %>% mutate(y=2*x) %>% plot_ly(x=x, y=y, mode="markers+lines")
   })
},
options=list(height=500)
)
```

## Page 2
```{r, echo=FALSE}
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Page 2"),
   mainPanel(fluidRow(plotlyOutput("plot"))
   )),
server = function(input, output) {
   output$plot = renderPlotly({
      data.frame(x=seq(1,5)) %>% mutate(y=3*x-2) %>% plot_ly(x=x, y=y, mode="markers+lines")
   })
},
options=list(height=500)
)
```
````

Comment: I just ran your code (after adding in library() calls to load plotly and dplyr. and both tabs contain a plot.

Comment: That's very interesting,  the plot in the second tab is definitely not displaying for me.  I am using shiny 0.13.2,  plotly 3.6.0,  rmarkdown 0.9.6,  everything should be up-to-date..  any idea what could be the issue?  Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to work for me as well. Only difference is that I'm using `rmarkdown 1.0`